# Setting background color on Internet Explorer Windows Media <video> or <object>

Tags: css, internet-explorer, video, html5-video, windows-media-player

I'm attempting to set the background color on a video object in Internet Explorer.  For both `<video>` with a WMV source and `<object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">` (Windows Media), the default background color is black and it seems that I can't change it.

I've tried setting the background color via CSS, via both inline styles and the stylesheet selecting `video, object`.  I've also tried adding a `bgcolor` param to the object both when adding it to the DOM and after it's loaded.

While I can examine the elements via JavaScript and the F12 tools and see that my CSS rule and bgcolor param are being applied, the video is still rendering with a black background.

It might be worth noting that I'm running the video in windowless mode, since it's embedded inline on a webpage.

(Applying the background color via CSS to a  works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  It's just Internet Explorer / Windows Media Player that's giving me trouble.)

Comment: Are you able to apply styles to any other HTML5 tags like <header>, <nav> etc?